# Is HTTPs required for Android/iOS app on local connection

Tags: android, ios, react-native, http, https

We are creating an app that connects to an IoT device (in Access Point mode) and sends WiFi credentials to the IoT device using http on a 192.168 (local) address. The app is developed using React Native.

Is https required for this connection when publishing to the App/Play Store? Or is adding an App Transport Security exception (iOS) / usesClearTextTraffic (Android manifest) recommended?

Comment: On Android you'd have to use useClearTextTraffic.  The OS does't know that the recipient is some weird device, it just knows you're trying to use HTTP, and without that it will fail security checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `usesCleartextTraffic` property to `true` otherwise in production mode, it won't work

```
<application
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```