# <Image> Source with port not working in Xaml with .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui

I will make this short, well I am trying to show a Image through Xaml using  Tag but I mage is not showing up.

I have this:

```
<Image Grid.RowSpan="4"
      Source="http://srvenvaisa.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/Imagenes/PT-1001.jpg"
      Aspect="AspectFill"
      HeightRequest="60"
      WidthRequest="60" />
```

Image is not showing up but the url works perfectly in browsers it shows the image.

And if I copy any imagen from the web it works and it shows up the image for example, this works good.

```
<Image Grid.RowSpan="4"
                       Source="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12487201/pexels-photo-12487201.jpeg"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="60"
                       WidthRequest="60" />
```

any approach how to solve this issue? and am I doing wrong? is it because of the port? :8080?
but in browsers it works perfectly.

Comment: Why aren’t you using SSL?

Comment: company requerimets. And we are in a dev mode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72030926/is-https-required-for-android-ios-app-on-local-connection

Comment: I did that but did not work. We just created a Image folder in our IIS using azure Virtual machine using windows. we put some images in that folder and in IIS we used the path for that folder. Idk if we need to set some special permission to that folder?

Comment: Are these images publicly accessible?

Comment: yes these images can be seen through any web browser.

Comment: Which platform did you test it on?